# Nontrivial subspace of a vector space has a unique complement?

Tags: linear-algebra

> Can it happen that a non-trivial subspace of a vector space $V$ (i.e.,
> a subspace different from both $0$ and $V$) has a unique complement?

I have trouble understanding why this question is worth arguing, and feel like I am missing something. If I have a complement $U$ of $V$ in $X$, then by definition $U\cap V$ is trivial and $U\cup V$ is $X$, so wouldn't $U$ be $(X-V)\cup\{0\}$?

Comment: What is $1$ here? It's not set theoretical complement, a complement of $U$ is also a subspace.

Comment: Sorry, it's zero

Answer (score 2):

The condition of complementarity is not that $U \cup V = X$, but that $U \oplus V = X$. In other words, the vectors in $X \setminus U$ don't need to be in $V$, but they need to be written as sums $u + v$ for $u \in U$ and $v \in V$. This gives some freedom in choosing $V$. For example, if $X = \mathbb{R}^2$, and $U$ is the $x$-axis, then $V$ can be any other line passing through the origin.

Put another way, the bases for $U$ and $V$ need to be linearly independent, but together span all of $X$.